# add_host - add all host

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I made a playbook that devid the hosts to windows and linux groups. this is the script (for now its just Linux and print the items that in the group):

```
---
 - name: firstPlaybook
   hosts: all
   gather_facts: true

   tasks:
   - name: Linux Group
     add_host:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       group: LinuxGroup
     when: hostvars[item].ansible_system == 'Linux'
     with_items: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }} "
     run_once: yes

   - name: dubug
     debug:
       msg: "{{ item }}"
     with_items: LinuxGroup
```

and when I run the script with -vvv this is what I saw in the tasks itself:

```
TASK [Linux Group] *************************************************************
task path: /home/opc/playbooks/playbook.yml:7
skipping: [windowsserver] => (item=windowsserver)  => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "windowsserver",
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
creating host via 'add_host': hostname=linuxserver
changed: [windowsserver] => (item=linuxserver) => {
    "add_host": {
        "groups": [
            "LinuxGroup"
        ],
        "host_name": "linuxserver",
        "host_vars": {
            "group": "LinuxGroup"
        }
    },
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "item": "linuxserver"
}
Perform task: TASK: dubug (N)o/(y)es/(c)ontinue: y

Perform task: TASK: dubug (N)o/(y)es/(c)ontinue: *******************************

TASK [dubug] *******************************************************************
task path: /home/opc/playbooks/playbook.yml:15
ok: [windowsserver] => (item=LinuxGroup) => {
    "msg": "LinuxGroup"
}
ok: [linuxserver] => (item=LinuxGroup) => {
    "msg": "LinuxGroup"
}
```

why its adding the windows server the the linux group even thought it suppose to be skipped (I changed the ips to windowsserver and linuxserver that I wont publish them)?

Answer (score 0):

All is working as expected. Take a look at

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups.LinuxGroup }}"
```

Comment: so why when I use the ping module on the linux group, its try to ping the windows server too?

Comment: You were right, with the dubug I discorver that the task run from each node on the list to the nodes in the group, so I added: delegate_to: localhost that it will run only from localhost.
I did not know that, can you refer me to the doc that explain it? and how playbooks works?